# Materialize autocomplete with dynamic data in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, materialize

I'm using materialize ui in an ASP.Net MVC application and I'm using an autocomplete control with dynamic data.

Here is my code,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
                <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
                <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jquery ajax call,

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', // your request type
        url: "/Home/GetData/",
        success: function (response) {
            var myArray = $.parseJSON(response);

            debugger;
            $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
                data: {
                    "Arizona (1)": null,
                    "Florida (2)": null,
                    "Georgia (3)": null,
                    "Hawaii(4)": null, 
                    "Idaho (5)": null,
                    "Illinois (6)": null
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It can accept data only in this format and this is my response,

```
"[["Arizona (1)"],["Florida (2)"],["Georgia (3)"],["Hawaii (4)"],["Idaho (5)"],["Illinois (6)"]]"
```

How do I convert my response into the format that autocomplete understands?

Comment: Does your response is:

"[[\"Arizona (1)\"],[\"Florida (2)\"],[\"Georgia (3)\"],[\"Hawaii (4)\"],[\"Idaho (5)\"],[\"Illinois (6)\"]]"

?

Comment: I get that response using -> var str = JSON.stringify(response);

Answer (score 27):

**Using ajax API call for materializecss input autocomplete**

I have modified as below to obtain autocomplete input for Countries.

You can get the list of country names from API https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Autocomplete
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name',
      success: function(response) {
        var countryArray = response;
        var dataCountry = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < countryArray.length; i++) {
          //console.log(countryArray[i].name);
          dataCountry[countryArray[i].name] = countryArray[i].flag; //countryArray[i].flag or null
        }
        $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
          data: dataCountry,
          limit: 5, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <label for="country">Autocomplete</label>
        <input type="text" id="country" class="autocomplete">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Good day. I can suggest a little different approach. Materialize autocomplete has method

> updateData

So if we want to get ajax to load data, we may add event listener to input field

```
   $(".autocomplete").each(function () {
    let self = this;
    $(this).autocomplete();
    $(this).on("input change", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/source/to/server/data',
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            data: {"some": "data"},
            success: function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                $(self).autocomplete("updateData", data/*should be object*/);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Not ideal for different data sources, but may be a starting point.

Comment: This answer ends up calling the url again on success fucntion as

Comment: This answer should be accepted because it'll never break on very large data. On down side it'll will hit API every time user try to input any character even remove them. you can restrict this by implementing time check to limit frequent hits. just like another search engine

Answer (score 0):

Not very fancy, but give it a try:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', // your request type
        url: "/Home/GetData/",
        success: function (response) {
            var myArray = $.parseJSON(response);
            var dataAC = {};
            for(var i=0;i<myArray[0].length;i++){
                eval("dataAC." + myArray[0][i] + " = null;");
            }
            debugger;
            $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
                data: dataAC
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I made a change like this: eval("\"" + myArray[0][i] + "\"" + " : null,"); but now it's giving me invalid : token error on : null

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your response through this way, in your case you don't need the first line of code.

```js
var responseData = JSON.parse(`[["Arizona (1)"],["Florida (2)"],["Georgia (3)"],["Hawaii (4)"],["Idaho (5)"],["Illinois (6)"]]`);

var acArray = [];
var acData = {};
responseData.forEach(res => {
  acArray.push(res.join())
})
acArray.forEach(acObj => {
  acData[acObj] = null;
})
console.log(acData)
```

Answer (score -3):

you can easily achieve the autocomplete functionality using the Devberidge plugin.

Get Devbridge plugin using https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {


              $("#country").devbridgeAutocomplete({
                //lookup: countries,
                serviceUrl:"getCountry.php", //tell the script where to send requests
                  type:'POST',


                  //callback just to show it's working
                  onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                     // $('#selection').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
                    },
                showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
                noSuggestionNotice: 'Sorry, no matching results',


              });

    });

  </script>
```

Here the getCountry.php file returns the JSON data.
For more info visit https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/materialize-css/materialize-css-framework-ajax-autocomplete-example-using-php