# MaterializeCSS Autocomplete PHP MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete, materialize

I need to make a autocomplete input in materialize css page,

I've tried this code but did not work. Do you have any idea how to make this possible?

From here [Autocomplete Textbox using jQuery, PHP and MySQL](https://www.codexworld.com/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-mysql/)

**index.php**

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'search.php'
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="skills">Skills: </label>
    <input id="skills" type="text">
  </div>
```

**search.php**

```php
<?php 
$dbHost = 'localhost'; 
$dbUsername = 'u969692298_dogs'; 
$dbPassword = 'dogs123'; 
$dbName = 'u969692298_dogs'; 
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName); 
$searchTerm = $_GET['term']; 
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM kennels WHERE name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY name ASC"); 
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { 
  $data[] = $row['name'];
} 
echo json_encode($data); 
?>
```

Comment: Does `search.php` exists? If so, post please the code.

Comment: it works great, but index.php dont work <?php
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'u969692298_dogs';
    $dbPassword = 'dogs123';
    $dbName = 'u969692298_dogs';
    
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
    
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
    
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM kennels WHERE name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY name ASC");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['name'];
    }
    
    echo json_encode($data);
?>

Comment: for more look at this link https://www.codexworld.com/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-mysql/

Comment: page without materializecss: http://prntscr.com/fvf6yp , page with materializecss: http://prntscr.com/fvf76x

Comment: Please answer my question, does `search.php` exist? You are now talking about `index.php`, maybe you need to rename it? Or change the code.

Comment: yes search.php exist

Comment: show the `search.php` codes

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:
The result from this snippet suggests country name when you start typing in input box with `materialize css` framework.

**Example with API GET request**

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  //Autocomplete
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name',
      success: function(response) {
        var countryArray = response;
        var dataCountry = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < countryArray.length; i++) {
          //console.log(countryArray[i].name);
          dataCountry[countryArray[i].name] = countryArray[i].flag; //countryArray[i].flag or null
        }
        $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
          data: dataCountry,
          limit: 5, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" name="name">
      <label for="autocomplete-input">Country Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above code by [`Jaikhlang Brahma` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43553324/13378977)

**Example with POST request**

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Autocomplete
  var inp_val = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

  var dataString = "name="+inp_val;
 
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'suggest-country.php',
      data: dataString,
      success: function(response) {
        var countryArray = response;
        var dataCountry = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < countryArray.length; i++) {
          //console.log(countryArray[i].name);
          dataCountry[countryArray[i].name] = countryArray[i].flag; //countryArray[i].flag or null
        }
        $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
          data: dataCountry,
          limit: 5, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" name="name">
      <label for="autocomplete-input">Country Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PHP (suggest-country.php)**

```
<?
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$dbHost = 'localhost'; 
$dbUsername = 'u969692298_dogs'; 
$dbPassword = 'dogs123'; 
$dbName = 'u969692298_dogs'; 
$conn = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName); 
$query = trim(str_replace("  ", " ", $_POST['name']));
$str = htmlspecialchars($query);
$q = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM kennels WHERE name = ? ORDER BY name ASC"); 
$sql->bind_param("s", $q);
$sql->execute();
$rs = $sql->get_result();
$arr = array();
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
 $arr["name"] .= $row["name"];
 $arr["flag"] .= $row["flag"];
}
// echo "<pre>".json_encode($arr)."</pre>";
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

This `PHP` code is pretty secure and working nicely.
For more relevancy use `MYSQL FULL TEXT SEARCH` or replace this `SQL` query

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM kennels WHERE name = ? ORDER BY name ASC"); 
$sql->bind_param("s", $q);
$sql->execute();
```

To this

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, " . " MATCH(name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance " . " FROM kennels" . " ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 8"); 
$sql->bind_param("s", $q);
$sql->execute();
$rs = $sql->get_result();
```

Hope this is helpful to you, I know how old this post is, but I want to help other newbies who are experiencing this problem.

Thank you